# extract class name from tag beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML code:

```
    <td class="image">
      <a href="/target/tt0111161/" title="Target Text 1">
       <img alt="target img" height="74" src="img src url" title="image title" width="54"/>
      </a>
     </td>
     <td class="title">
      <span class="wlb_wrapper" data-caller-name="search" data-size="small" data-tconst="tt0111161">
      </span>
      <a href="/target/tt0111161/">
       Other Text
      </a>
      <span class="year_type">
       (2013)
      </span>
```

I am trying to use beautiful soup to parse certain elements into a tab-delimited file. 
I got some great help and have:

```
for td in soup.select('td.title'):
 span = td.select('span.wlb_wrapper')
 if span:
     print span[0].get('data-tconst') # To get `tt0082971`
```

Now I want to get "Target Text 1" .

I've tried some things like the above text such as:

```
for td in soup.select('td.image'): #trying to select the <td class="image"> tag
img = td.select('a.title') #from inside td I now try to look inside the a tag that also has the word title
if img:
    print img[2].get('title') #if it finds anything, then I want to return the text in class 'title'
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at extracting it yourself?

Comment: I've edited the post above

Comment: another thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369344/beautifulsoup4-how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-the-class-name-of-specific-tag/41369459#41369459

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're trying to get a different td based on the class (i.e. td class="image" and td class="title" you can use beautiful soup as a dictionary to get the different classes.

This will find all the td class="image" in the table.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = """
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="image">
           <a href="/target/tt0111161/" title="Target Text 1">
            <img alt="target img" height="74" src="img src url" title="image title" width="54"/>
           </a>
          </td>
          <td class="title">
           <span class="wlb_wrapper" data-caller-name="search" data-size="small" data-tconst="tt0111161">
           </span>
           <a href="/target/tt0111161/">
            Other Text
           </a>
           <span class="year_type">
            (2013)
           </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
tbl = soup.find('table')
rows = tbl.findAll('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    for col in cols:
        if col.has_attr('class') and col['class'][0] == 'image':
            hrefs = col.find_all('a')
            for href in hrefs:
                print href.get('title')

        elif col.has_attr('class') and col['class'][0] == 'title':
            spans = col.find_all('span')
            for span in spans:
                if span.has_attr('class') and span['class'][0] == 'wlb_wrapper':
                    print span.get('data-tconst')
```

Comment: Thanks, can I also add in statement to retrieve the value for the "data-tconst" tag?

Comment: yep, you can add an elif statement that looks for td's with title, pasting code in a comment failed, so I will just update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, now I just added `def getinfo:` before all that.  Can I write getinfo to a CSV?

Comment: I've personally never written to csv, but you should be able to open a file before the iteration and instead of printing out the values, write them to a file.  After the iterator, save the file.

Answer (score 0):

`span.wlb_wrapper` is a selector used to select `<span class="wlb_wrapper" data-caller-name="search" data-size="small" data-tconst="tt0111161">`. Refer [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#type-selectors) & [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) for more information on selectors

change this in your python code `span = td.select('span.wlb_wrapper')` to `span = td.select('span')` & also `span = td.select('span.year_type')`  and see what it returns.

If you try above and analyze what `span` holds you will get what you want.

Comment: I've edited the body text to show what I attempted to do in my code.  I've tried changing span.wlb_wrapper to just span but it now just returns a value of "None'