# beautifulsoup4: how to retrieve a list of the class name of specific tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I get that from beautifulsoup4:

```
<tr class="Details"> <td class=" s-12-to-15 ">ABC</td> <td class="s-15-to-18 ">DEF</td> <td class=" s-18-to-21 ">GHI</td></tr>
```

how can I get:

```
s-12-to-15 ABC
s-15-to-18 DEF
s-18-to-21 GHI
```

I looked into bf4 documentation and several stack questions about retrieving class name but without success. I can't the way to retrieve these class. (I know I could parse the string to get the result but I'm interested to learn about bf4).

Comment: I tried more than 20 combination using var.find('td') and var.("tr", {"class"[]) var.('td.class') etc.

Comment: @depperm I guess you downvoted me. Thanks to elrull I found the .join(s['class']) I was looking for. I'd be interested to know where I could have find it in the bf4 documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for s in soup.find_all('td'):
    print ''.join(s['class']).strip(), s.text
```

Comment: python35 syntax:
for s in dayPrecipit.find_all('td'):
 print(''.join(s['class']).strip(), s.text)

Comment: the `''.join(listToConvert)` convert the list to string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618878/how-to-convert-list-to-string

Comment: the `variable['class']` send the class name

Comment: for those looking for the docs: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes